# TabLayout crashing after updating support library to 23.2.0

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library

I am using `TabLayout` from the design library with the `ViewPager`, linking them using the function `setupWithViewPager`. The app is crashing in scenarios where it recreates the tabs, after the tab contents have been changed. Crash trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tab belongs to a different TabLayout.
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:433)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:772)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:763)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:715)
```

The crash is occuring after updating to support library 23.2.0, **doesn't reproduce till v23.1.1.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found that this is an internal bug in Support library v23.2.0, registered at : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201827

Answer (score 2):

**This was bug** reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201827

But after release of Android Support Library, [revision 23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This is fixed now.**

just update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same problem, and then I found the newer `TabLayout` use a pool to cache Tab.
in 23.1.1

```
public Tab newTab() {
    return new Tab(this);
}
```

and in 23.2.0

```
public Tab newTab() {
    Tab tab = sTabPool.acquire();
    if (tab == null) {
        tab = new Tab(this);
    }
    tab.mView = createTabView(tab);
    return tab;
}
```

so if you use `newTab()` to create a Tab, and for some reason you didn't add it to the `TableLayout`. the next time you enter another activity with a `TabLayout`, this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

I can still see this issue in support lib version: 25.3.1. So to avoid the crash, removedAllTabs() and created a new instance for the tab again and added to Tablayout.

```
 gauge_tab.removeAllTabs()
 gauge_tab.addTab(gauge_tab.newTab().setText(R.string.flash_gauge_04))
 gauge_tab.addTab(gauge_tab.newTab().setText(R.string.flash_gauge_06))
 gauge_tab.addTab(gauge_tab.newTab().setText(R.string.flash_gauge_08))
```